# Prolog - is the following query satisfied?

Tags: prolog

I am doing exercise from the following [link](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse7)

Here is knowledge base:

```
house_elf(dobby). 
witch(hermione). 
witch(’McGonagall’). 
witch(rita_skeeter). 
magic(X):-  house_elf(X). 
magic(X):-  wizard(X). 
magic(X):-  witch(X).
```

I am expecting the following query to return true:

```
?-  magic(’McGonagall’).
```

However, my SWI-Prolog (AMD64, Multi-threaded, version 7.6.4) on Windows 7 returns the following:

```
ERROR: Stream user_input:450:4 Syntax error: Unexpected end of clause
?- magic('McGonagall').
ERROR: Undefined procedure: wizard/1
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] wizard('McGonagall')
ERROR:    [8] magic('McGonagall') at c:/users/some_user/google drive/projects/nlp/prolog/code/ex2_2.pl:6
ERROR:    [7] <user>
   Exception: (9) wizard('McGonagall') ? creep
   Exception: (8) magic('McGonagall') ? creep
?-
```

Why does it fail?

Comment: You defined `with` facts, but you call `wizard/1`, which is *not* defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `magic/1` predicate, you call `wizard/1`, which is *not* defined:

```
magic(X):-  house_elf(X). 
magic(X):-  wizard(X).
magic(X):-  witch(X).
```

The result is that Prolog errors, since it calls a predicate that is nowhere defined.

You can for example define a `wizard/1` predicate that *always* fails:

```
% a world without wizards (if you do not specify extra wizards)
wizard(_) :- fail.
```

or populate your "world" with wizards, like:

```
wizard(dumbledore).
wizard(remus_lupin).
%% ...
```

Comment: Thank you, then it seems this exercise in poorly structured, since it will always fail no matter what query is posed.